# How I can Print form data set on linearlayout through Bluetooth printer

Tags: android, android-layout, read-eval-print-loop

Hi all i want to connect to Bluetooth printer and print a receipt for user data set on linear layout on textview as above

[image]

Comment: Which printer you using?? Zebra? AEM ? printer name please?

Comment: is it depends on printer hw ??

Comment: Not actually i just confirming,,,,,See my ans below it could help,,,

Comment: @Ishrat I want to know how to give the printers the above formate

Comment: @Ishrat i am not able to see your ans

Comment: If you looking for format as above, then it's depend on Printer few printer support \n for new line few support \r\n or some support CPCL language,,,Formatting depends on printer.

Answer (score 1):

__________Print Method____________

```
private void bluetoothSendData(String text) {
        if (LogConfig.tracking)
            Log.i("bluetoothSendData()", text);
        try {
            mBTSocket.getOutputStream().write(decodeText(text));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (LogConfig.enable)
                Log.e(TAG, "Send data error: ", e);
        }

    }
```

_________If you need formatted text to be print then use_______________

```
private byte[] decodeText(String text) throws CharacterCodingException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String encoding = "your supported encoding";
        Charset charset = Charset.forName(encoding);
        CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
        CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
        ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(text));
        CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
        String s = cbuf.toString();
        return s.getBytes(encoding);
    }


BluetoothSocket mBTSocket = null;
```

_________________initMethod()___________________

```
mBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBTDevice = getBTDeviceRegisteredPrinter();
```

---

____________connect method_______________

```
mBTSocket = mBTDevice
                            .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID_SECURE);
mBTSocket.connect();
```

Get Device using below code

```
private BluetoothDevice getBTDeviceRegisteredPrinter() {

        BluetoothDevice BTDevice = null;    
        if (mBTAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                // Loop through paired devices
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    if (getRegisteredPrinter().equals("Your Printer")) {
                        if (device.getName().startsWith("see paired name")) {
                            if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                                BTDevice = device;
                                mBTAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return BTDevice;

    }
```